# SQL INNER JOIN with more than one condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have the below query which works fine but I want to modify it by adding another condition but am not sure how to go about it. What I want to add is shown in the second query but its not working.

```
   $results_pref_school1 = $db->query('SELECT mps.mps_client_ec_no,mcs.mcs_client_ec_no
                                          FROM match_pref_schools AS mps
                                          INNER JOIN match_current_schools AS mcs
                                          ON mps.mps_school_id = mcs.mcs_school_id
                                          WHERE mcs.mcs_id IN (SELECT MIN(mcs.mcs_id) 
                                                              FROM match_current_schools AS mcs
                                                              GROUP BY mcs.mcs_school_id)
                                          ORDER BY mcs.mcs_id');
```

I need only results with an 'A' status

```
  $results_pref_school1 = $db->query('SELECT mps.mps_client_ec_no,mcs.mcs_client_ec_no
                                      FROM match_pref_schools AS mps
                                      INNER JOIN match_current_schools AS mcs
                                      ON mps.mps_school_id = mcs.mcs_school_id
                                      WHERE mcs.mcs_id IN (SELECT MIN(mcs.mcs_id) 
                                                          FROM match_current_schools AS mcs
                                                          GROUP BY mcs.mcs_school_id)
                                      AND mps.mps_status = "A" 
                                      AND mcs.mcs_status = "A"
                                      ORDER BY mcs.mcs_id');
```

Comment: When you go to the doctor, do you also just say "I'm sick"?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain I'm answering what you're trying to ask, but you can have multiple conditions in `on` clauses by using brackets

```
select
    *
from
    table_1
    inner join table_2 on(
        table_2.column_1 = table_1.column
        and (
            table_2.other_column = 'value'
            or table_2.other_column = 'other value'
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT mps.mps_client_ec_no,mcs.mcs_client_ec_no
FROM match_pref_schools AS mps
INNER JOIN match_current_schools AS mcs
    ON mps.mps_school_id = mcs.mcs_school_id
    AND mps.mps_status = "A" 
    AND mcs.mcs_status = "A"
WHERE mcs.mcs_id IN (
    SELECT MIN(mcs.mcs_id) 
    FROM match_current_schools AS mcs
    GROUP BY mcs.mcs_school_id)
    ORDER BY mcs.mcs_id
)
```

Comment: What is this? The infinite monkey cage?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If enough of us supply random answers to poorly defined questions then surely, eventually, one of us will be right. Yes, but I'm not convinced that that's best way to develop SO as a resource.